# Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop frozen after installing in Hyper V

Tags: 22.04

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop minimal installation on Hyper-V machine on top of Azure Windows host machine. After starting the machine the desktop appears but it comes frozen. Icons are not seen and unable to do any action. I tried re-starting the machine couple of times. After login it comes like that. It did not help. Any clues.

It comes as below
[image: Desktop]

I have selected Generation-2 VM, enabled TPM Module and Secure Boot is disabled

Comment: I had recently an identical problem with a local installation of Ubuntu 22.04 in Hyper-V. Oddly enough, an installation of Kubuntu 22.04 on the same machine works perfectly fine.